# Function used to check if a variable's string starts with vowel?

Tags: python

I am doing a sort of MadLibs thing and I need to check if three of my variables start with a vowel, and then tack "a" or "an" in front.
I have this,

```
def vowelcheck(variable):
    if variable[0] == "a" or variable[0] == "e" or variable[0] == "i" or variable[0] == "o" or variable[0] == "u":
        variable = "an " + variable
    else:
        variable = "a " + variable;
```

and then

```
vowelcheck(noun1)
vowelcheck(noun2)
vowelcheck(noun3)
```

after the variables, but it doesn't do anything to the words.
What can I change about this to make it work?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, and its input is immutable, hence your function is without effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 'variable' argument of your function is a copy of the words noun1, noun2, nound2. you indeed modify 'variable', but it does not modify nouns.

try instead:

```
def vowelcheck(variable):
    if variable[0] == "a" or variable[0] == "e" or variable[0] == "i" or variable[0] == "o" or variable[0] == "u":
        variable = "an " + variable
    else:
        variable = "a " + variable
    return variable

noun1, noun2, noun3 = (vowelcheck(noun1), vowelcheck(noun2), vowelcheck(noun3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, function arguments are passed by value, not by reference.  So you're only changing the local variable `variable`, not the passed-in string.

Try something like:

```
def vowelcheck(word):
    if word[0] in "aeiou":
        return "an " + word
    else:
        return "a " + word


noun1 = vowelcheck(noun1)
noun2 = vowelcheck(noun2)
noun3 = vowelcheck(noun3)
```

Comment: You pass arguments by value, but the value being passed is a reference. When you invoke `vowelcheck(noun1)`, you pass a reference to the object referenced by `noun1`. If `noun1` was a mutable object, the changes to the object would be seen after the function returns. I understand what you meant, but I believe the wording is unclear.

Comment: I don't get this totally, if the `variable` `noun1` is defined: `noun1 = 'door'` then `print vowelcheck(noun1)` will output `a door`